# Are questions about Yahoo Answers on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A curious notion popped into my head just now. It occurs to me that Yahoo Answers theoretically could be considered a Web App. As such, would questions about Yahoo Answers be on topic here? I don't have any questions about it as I stay as far from that place as I can but I am curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason for questions on Yahoo Answers to be off-topic. As long the question involves how to use it, rather than Why does Yahoo Answers do x, it is fine for Web Apps

Comment: omg y du usrs on Y1a tipe lyke dis al da tym?